# count with where query to code by use sequelize

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js

i want  change this query to code by use sequelize and node.js depend on where

```
select COUNT(gender) as genderCount from customers where gender = "male"
```

but i don't know how to add where

this original code:

```
 Customer.findAll({
      attributes: { 
        include: [[Sequelize.fn("COUNT", Sequelize.col("gender")), "genderCount"]]  }
      }).then(data => {
      res.send(data)
    })
```

Comment: You have two questions. How 'make another count' looks like? Need more details and focus

Comment: select COUNT(gender) as genderCount from customers where gender = "male" query to code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve it from query:

```
select COUNT(gender) as genderCount from customers where gender = "male"
```

to code sequelize :

```
await   Customer.findAll({
  attributes: { 
    include: [[Sequelize.fn("COUNT", Sequelize.col('gender')), "genderCount"]] ,  
  },
  where:[{"gender":'male'}]
  }).then(data => {
  res.send(data)
})
```

Answer (score 4):

For `"sequelize": "^5.21.3"`:

Option 1.

```js
const customers = await Customer.findAll({
    attributes: [[Sequelize.fn('COUNT', Sequelize.col('gender')), 'genderCount']],
    where: {
      gender: 'male',
    },
    raw: true,
});
```

The execution result:

```
Executing (default): SELECT COUNT("gender") AS "genderCount" FROM "customers" AS "Customer" WHERE "Customer"."gender" = 'male';
[ { genderCount: '3' } ]
```

Option 2. You can use [Model.count()](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-count).

> Count the number of records matching the provided where clause.

```js
const customers = await Customer.count({ col: 'gender', where: { gender: 'male' } });
```

The execution result:

```
Executing (default): SELECT count("gender") AS "count" FROM "customers" AS "Customer" WHERE "Customer"."gender" = 'male';
```

The above examples base on data records in the database:

[image]

Comment: option 1 exactly  what i doing 
but option 2 is new for me 
Thanks very much for the answer, I appreciate it